# Сохранение файла в csv формат

Tags: python, парсер, pandas, dataframe, csv

имеется csv файл такого формата:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Загружаю его, работаю с ним и пытаюсь его сохранить с помощью pandas в формате с разделенной запятой:

Загрузка:
`df1 = pd.read_csv('../input/FILE.csv', delimiter=';')`

Сохранение: `df1.to_csv('FILE.csv', decimal='.', index=True)`

Хочу получить дробные числа с точкой и значения через запятую, по первой строчке это было бы:

```
0,,0,,,,0.0156,25.49019623,64,100,801,7.849999905,22,-0.0078,,SmoothCondition,LowCongestionCondition,0
```

Получаю `0,,0,,,,"0,0156","25,49019623",64,100,801,"7,849999905",22,"-0,0078",,SmoothCondition,LowCongestionCondition,0`

Как избавиться от кавычек и вместо запятой определить точку?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Похоже в исходном CSV файле использовалась `,` в качестве *десятичного разделителя*. По умолчанию функция [`pd.read_csv(..., decimal='.')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) использует точку в качестве десятичного разделителя, поэтому при парсинге вещественных чисел с запятой в качестве десятичного разделителя, ячейка `"0,0156"` будет прочитана как *строка*.

Для решения данной проблемы следует указать явно `decimal=','` при чтении файла:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('../input/FILE.csv', delimiter=';', decimal=',')
```